# How use JQuery/Javascript to scroll down a page when the cursor at the top or bottom edge of the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, draggable, viewport

Simple, **I just would like to have it so when a user is dragging an item and they reach the very bottom or top of the viewport *(10px or so)*, the page *(about 3000px long)* gently scrolls down or up, until they move their cursor *(and thus the item being dragged)* out of the region**.

An item is an li tag which uses jquery to make the list items draggable. To be specific:

- ../jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js
- http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js

I currently use window.scrollBy(x=0,y=3) to scroll the page and have the variables of:

1. e.pageY ... provides absolute Y-coordinates of cursor on page (not relative to screen)
2. $.scrollTop() ... provides offset from top of page (when scroll bar is all the way up, it is 0)
3. $.height()... provides the height of viewable area in the user's browser/viewport
4. body.offsetHeight ... height of the entire page

How can I achieve this and which event best accommodates this (currently its in mouseover)?
         My ideas:

1. use a an if/else to check if it is in top region or bottom, scroll up if e.pageY is showing it is in the top, down if e.page& is in bottom, and then calling the $('li').mouseover() event to iterate through...

   2. Use a do while loop... this has worked moderately well actually, but is hard to stop from scrolling to far. But I am not sure how to control the iterations....

My latest attempt:

```
          ('li').mouseover(function(e) {

            totalHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;
            cursor.y = e.pageY;
            var papaWindow = window;
            var $pxFromTop = $(papaWindow).scrollTop();
            var $userScreenHeight = $(papaWindow).height();
            var iterate = 0;

            do {
                papaWindow.scrollBy(0, 2);
                iterate++;
                console.log(cursor.y, $pxFromTop, $userScreenHeight);
            }

            while (iterate < 20);
      });
```

Comment: FYI, I'm just worried about new browsers, mainly FF and Chrome... IE 7 or less doesn't exist in my "world"

Comment: hi, have you now got a working solution for this problem? can you post it? i have a similar problem posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222047/how-to-scroll-when-cursor-is-on-the-edge-of-div#comment14738038_11222047

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Works pretty well now, user just needs to "jiggle" the mouse when dragging items sometimes to keep scrolling, but for scrolling just with mouse position its pretty solid. Here is what I finally ended up using:**

```
 $("li").mouseover(function(e) {

  e = e || window.event; var cursor = { y: 0 }; cursor.y = e.pageY; //Cursor YPos
  var papaWindow = parent.window;
  var $pxFromTop = $(papaWindow).scrollTop();
  var $userScreenHeight = $(papaWindow).height();

  if (cursor.y > (($userScreenHeight + $pxFromTop) / 1.25)) {

         if ($pxFromTop < ($userScreenHeight * 3.2)) {

                   papaWindow.scrollBy(0, ($userScreenHeight / 30));
             }
        }
  else if (cursor.y < (($userScreenHeight + $pxFromTop) * .75)) {

        papaWindow.scrollBy(0, -($userScreenHeight / 30));

        }

   }); //End mouseover()
```

Comment: The *if ($pxFromTop < ($userScreenHeight * 3.2))* is so that the user cannot scroll down past the bottom of the list

Comment: There should be a }); after your code. It throws errors otherwise. (I couldn't edit because it's less than 6 characters)

Comment: Thanks @LunaticNeko , I updated it, must have missed that in the copy paste

Answer (score 1):

This won't work as the event only fires while you're mouse is over the li.

```
('li').mouseover(function(e) { });
```

You need to be able to tell the position of the mouse relative to the viewport when an item is being dragged. When the users starts to drag an item attach an 'mousemove' event to the body and then in that check the mouse position and scroll when necessary.

```
$("body").on("mousemove", function(event) {
// Check mouse position - scroll if near bottom or top
});
```

Dont forget to remove your event when the user stops dragging.

```
$("body").off("mousemove", function(event) {
// Check mouse position - scroll if near bottom or top
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jon! I'll work on trying to implement it with this idea, but from first glance this certainly seems to solve my dilemma of which event to use. If you can offer anything additional on the formula/logic for calculating cursor position relative to the current viewport I would love to hear it as well! THANK YOU!

Comment: Most certainly will accept your answer as long as I can get it to work. I didnt forget about you! (But the mouse positioning logic is really stumping me right now, worst case Ill accept yours since you answered first with helpful information)

Comment: What's stumping you in particular?

Comment: Basically, working with the variables aforementioned, trying to find a dynamic way to calculate where the mouse is, and decide if I should scroll up or down. Additionally, figuring out how to loop the effect or iterate it until the user moves their mouse or lets go of the li item they are dragging. Something like: **if (cursor.y > scrolltop() + $userScreenHeight) { scrollBy(0,-rate) } else if ( cursor.y < scrolltop() + $userScreenHeight) {scrollBy(0,rate) }**. Would prefer to dynamically calculate rate, but hard coding it as 3 is fine and gives a reasonable scroll that the user can see.

Comment: You shouldn't need to iterate it - the mousemove event will fire every time the mouse is moved. If you add the event when the dragging starts and remove it when the dragging stops then you don't need to worry about anything except working out the distance of the mouse from the top or bottom of the screen. Also you could vary the rate by increasing it the nearer the mouse is to the top or bottom of the screen (though i would get it working with a constant scroll rate and worry about that afterwards).

Comment: Yes, but then I find the user has to "jiggle" the piece they are dragging to continue the desired effect... but it's not the end of the world, I'd take it as a 1.0 version for now. Thanks again Jon!

Comment: Of course, how silly of me! Would it work if you changed it from a mousemove to mouseover event?

Comment: Yes!! Mouseover works much better actually (I think since technically the mouse isn't moving, the page is scrolling and the mouse is stationary, is why mousemove() wasn't as smooth as I liked. Smart man Jon!

Answer (score 1):

This may not be exactly what you want, but it might help. It will auto-scroll when the mouse is over the 'border of the screen' (a user defined region). Say you have a 40px wide bar on the right of the screen, if the mouse reaches the first 1px, it will start scrolling. Each px you move into it, the speed will increase. It even has a nice easing animation.

http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/v1-2.htm

Comment: Looks interesting, I'll check it out tomorrow morning

Comment: Certainly helpful, and probably could be the most elegant form of this solution, however I would need to hack it up a little. Currently, the plugin is only configured to scroll left and right, NOT down and up. I imagine it shouldn't be too hard to change that, and if you could it would be the perfect solution. Too much work for now though! Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I get a weekly newsletter (email) from CodeProject, and it had some stuff that certainly looks like it will solve my problem... hopefully this can help others:

1. http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrollorama/ -- JQuery based and animates the scroll
2. https://github.com/IanLunn/jQuery-Parallax -- JQuery based, similar to above
3. http:// remysharp. com/2009/01/26/element-in-view-event-plugin/ -- JQuery, detects whether an element is currently in view of the user (super helpful for this issue!)
4. Also the site in #2 had some interesting code:

   ```
   var windowHeight = $window.height();
   var navHeight = $('#nav').height() / 2;
   var windowCenter = (windowHeight / 2);
   var newtop = windowCenter - navHeight;
   //ToDo: Find a way to use these vars and my original ones to determine scroll regions
   ```