# Show soft keyboard when AppBar is active using focus makes the content jump back to the top

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone, winjs, uwp

Currently just started developing a UWP WinJS app, testing on Windows 10 Mobile.

I have an appbar and a contenteditable div - if I press a button on the appbar to bold some word in the content area, the div will bold it, but will also jump completely to the top when editor.focus() is called. I'd like for it to stay in its current position.

What I'm trying to do is to have the keyboard appear even when a button is pressed on the AppBar. (Without editor.focus(), the keyboard disappears on button tap.) Unfortunately, with that additional line of code, I have the above scrolling issue.

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tristique convallis aliquet. Proin ac urna ut diam luctus facilisis vel in ligula. Morbi porta volutpat est eget semper. Sed elementum tincidunt libero. Cras a felis leo. Fusce lacinia turpis vel turpis facilisis sollicitudin. Suspendisse blandit, nisi gravida fermentum placerat, velit ipsum volutpat mi, ut finibus enim mauris at massa. Etiam placerat et mi eget iaculis. Aliquam et semper nisl. Integer id magna non sapien tempus suscipit at eget sem. Integer quam risus, placerat sit amet iaculis ac, ultrices non diam. Aliquam at convallis velit, vitae iaculis lectus. Morbi non orci eget mi placerat aliquet. Sed at neque a eros efficitur egestas. Donec sed luctus leo, ac ullamcorper dui.

    Nullam volutpat ultricies leo, ut congue risus egestas euismod. Suspendisse nisi ligula, volutpat id tempor convallis, facilisis in justo. Nulla porta neque eget ante tincidunt pellentesque. Integer felis libero, rutrum eu interdum eu, finibus a felis. Vestibulum vel est dictum, tempor ex vel, facilisis lorem. Nulla facilisi. Nulla ut ornare tortor, vitae blandit augue. Quisque imperdiet pretium turpis, ac fermentum diam imperdiet vitae. Pellentesque vel mollis odio. Quisque tempus eget neque non pretium.

    Cras eu velit sit amet dolor pulvinar ultricies at id lectus. Suspendisse quis metus sem. Etiam lectus mauris, lobortis volutpat consectetur at, sodales in nisl. Fusce euismod magna in leo tempor, quis bibendum leo gravida. Nulla varius velit vel ultrices sollicitudin. Morbi at odio efficitur, iaculis odio ut, auctor mauris. Phasellus nec lacus arcu. Duis porttitor, urna sit amet tempor dapibus, velit libero malesuada erat, eget pulvinar velit quam id leo. Quisque vulputate vehicula ante, vel condimentum dui consectetur eget.

    Curabitur lobortis porta justo quis pulvinar. Aliquam quam nisl, aliquam vel risus et, semper molestie nulla. Aenean mollis facilisis odio vel convallis. Suspendisse vestibulum nec sapien ut pretium. Duis vehicula, mi sed rutrum luctus, odio magna hendrerit nisl, laoreet eleifend augue neque vestibulum dui. Proin vitae metus convallis, condimentum enim in, volutpat nisl. Aliquam at est id felis placerat fermentum. Duis suscipit commodo convallis. Aliquam imperdiet mollis tortor, sit amet placerat tellus malesuada in. Nunc fringilla sem lorem, nec efficitur purus lobortis mollis. Duis non eros aliquam, luctus libero sed, ullamcorper odio.

    Fusce orci est, rutrum non urna a, finibus suscipit dolor. Mauris suscipit mi ut dolor cursus, quis laoreet est porta. Etiam bibendum fringilla turpis et sagittis. Aenean vehicula maximus dui ut pretium. Vestibulum iaculis id sapien nec condimentum. Donec a aliquet enim. Donec non mauris convallis, tincidunt elit sit amet, ultrices nulla. Duis vel auctor nisl, vitae ultrices mi. Suspendisse potenti. Vivamus sit amet lacus urna. Fusce a sagittis risus. Cras facilisis porta purus, vitae scelerisque mauris vehicula eu. 
</div>

<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar" id="appBar" data-win-options="{placement: 'bottom', sticky: 'true'}" style="background-color: #e6e6e6;">       
        <button  data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{id: 'boldBtn', icon: 'bold', section:'selection', tooltip:'bold'}"></button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
element.querySelector("#boldBtn").addEventListener("click", toggleBold, false);

function toggleBold() {
    document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
    editor.focus();   // this will cause the div to jump back to the top if it's not already at the top
}
```

Tried another solution using [tryShow()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane.tryshow.ASPX), to detect when the keyboard is about to be hidden. Once detected, force the keyboard to appear. Also, show the AppBar (since it disappeared), place the editor in focus and then scroll back to where you were before. This takes a few seconds to execute and the scrolling is too obvious for it to be a viable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to scroll the screen to your selected position, you should calculate the `offset` of the coordinate, which is moved cause by the showing of a software keyboard.

Here is my `Javascript` code:

(function () {
    "use strict";

```
var app = WinJS.Application;
var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;

var userHeight, cursorY0, range;

app.onactivated = function (args) {
    if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
        if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
            // TODO: This application has been newly launched. Initialize your application here.
        } else {
            // TODO: This application was suspended and then terminated.
            // To create a smooth user experience, restore application state here so that it looks like the app never stopped running.
        }
        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().done(
            function () {



                //var editor = document.getElementById("editor");
                //editor.addEventListener("click", toggleBold, false);
                var button = document.getElementById("boldBtn");
                var text = document.getElementById("editor");
                var oRange = document.createRange();
                button.addEventListener("click", toggleBold, false);
                text.addEventListener('mouseup',function(e){

                    if (window.getSelection) {
                        var selection = window.getSelection();
                    } else if (document.selection) {
                        var selection = document.selection.createRange();
                    }
                    range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
                    cursorY0 = window.event.pageY;
                    console.log(cursorY0);
                })
                /*text.addEventListener("click", function () {
                    cursorY0 = window.event.pageY;
                    console.log(cursorY0);
                }, false);*/
                //console.log(window.innerHeight);
                userHeight = window.innerHeight;
            })
            );
    }
};

app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {
    // TODO: This application is about to be suspended. Save any state that needs to persist across suspensions here.
    // You might use the WinJS.Application.sessionState object, which is automatically saved and restored across suspension.
    // If you need to complete an asynchronous operation before your application is suspended, call args.setPromise().
};

function toggleBold() {
    var text = document.getElementById("editor");
    //Array.prototype.slice.apply(document.querySelectorAll("b")).forEach(function (b) {
    //    b.parentNode.replaceChild(b.firstChild, b);
    //});

    text.focus();
    var currentHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var cursorY1 = window.event.pageY;
    if (cursorY1 > currentHeight) {
        window.scrollTo(0, currentHeight - (cursorY1 - cursorY0));
    }

    var selectionContents = range.extractContents();
    var boldDom = document.createElement("b");

    boldDom.appendChild(selectionContents);
    range.insertNode(boldDom);


}

app.start();
})();
```

This is a Non-JQuery method, I think you can also import a JQuery package, and use the [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113364/how-use-jquery-javascript-to-scroll-down-a-page-when-the-cursor-at-the-top-or-bo) here to calculate the `offset`.

Comment: Hi panda, I replaced your text.style.fontWeight = "bold" with document.execCommand('bold', false, null); , since I only want to bold text that I've selected. When I select a word to bold near the the bottom of my text, the text jumps up after I've pressed the bold button. Still experimenting with it right now, but wondering if you have the same issue?

Comment: OK, for the `text jump` screen scroll problem, my old answer can already fix this. And for `bold selected text` problem, i've just edited my code.

Comment: Got it working after setting a specified height for my editor div. Thanks for your help!